# Cron skipping over a portion of BASH script

Tags: bash, cron

I have a BASH script located at `/usr/local/bin/zfs_scrub.sh`. Content of the script is listed below.
The script is executable and I can run it as root (sudo) and it performs as expected.

I have edited roots crontab `sudo crontab -e` and added the following line. (10 mins is for my test env, in reality this will run once per week.)

`*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/zfs_scrub.sh`

When I run the script manually, I get 6 lines written to the log as expected

```
2013 04 26 14:19:17 :  
2013 04 26 14:19:17 : Starting ZFS Scrub
2013 04 26 14:19:17 : Starting Scrub on tankm
2013 04 26 14:19:17 : pool 'tankm' is healthy
2013 04 26 14:19:17 : Ending Scrub on tankm
2013 04 26 14:19:17 : Ending ZFS Scrub
```

When it is run by cron, the following occurs

```
2013 04 26 15:50:02 :  
2013 04 26 15:50:02 : Starting ZFS Scrub
2013 04 26 15:50:02 : Ending ZFS Scrub
```

So it appear to me that cron is either skipping over the loop in the code, or is not finding the zfs storage pools when it executes `zpool list -H -o name`.

Any input would be appreciated.

---

### zfs_scrub.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/home/declan/log/zfs_scrub
LOG_LAST=/home/declan/log/zfs_scrub_last

LogEntry () {echo "$(date "+%Y %m %d %T") ; $1" >>$LOG_FILE 2>&1; }

while getopts ":n" opt; do
    case $opt in
    n)
        cp $LOG_FILE $LOG_LAST
        rm $LOG_FILE
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        ;;
    esac
done

logEntry " "
LogEntry "Starting ZFS Scrub"

for POOL in $(zpool list -H -o name) ; do
    LogEntry "Starting Scrub on $POOL"
    zpool scrub $POOL 2>/dev/null
    LogEntry "$(zpool status -x $POOL 2>&1)"
    LogEntry "Ending Scrub on $POOL"
done

LogEntry "Ending ZFS Scrub"
```

Comment: @NCao - add your comment as an answer and I'll upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` usually does not use the exact same `PATH` as in your shell, which explain why the script run by `cron` does not find the `zpool` executable.

If `zpool` is e.g. in `/usr/sbin`, add to the beginning of your script:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
```

Or if you need just one executable which does not depend on the `PATH` itself you can simply use its full path `/usr/sbin/zpool`.

Comment: Or you can invoke it as `/usr/sbin/zpool` (assuming it doesn't invoke something else that needs `/usr/sbin` in `$PATH`).

Comment: The actual location was `/sbin/zpool`
I just edited the three lines that call that to include the full path and it is working perfectly.
Now off to lean how to email the results..... I'll be back here soon for sure ;-)